# Refresh method is not working in Imagelistview

Tags: c#, .net

Why is not working Refresh method in ImageListView, Can you give me altenative solution
imageListView1.Refresh();

Comment: Please be careful when selecting tags, so you don't select the completely wrong ones (I changed the C language tag to the C# language tag for you). Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

if you make it binding automatically from columns
try this:

```
imageListView1.Items.Clear();
imageListView1.Refresh();
```

else override Data bindings by your new data .

Comment: All Images are Deleted in Imagelistview, I want to refresh it

Comment: Explain please! what you want to do with refresh? you add new data? or what?

Comment: If I add new data in imagelistview, and i will move another location, But still show ? , If I will add 5images in imagelistview and 2image images move another location ,There will show 5images i have moved images, still show 3images but there 5images

Comment: can you try 'imageListView1.Update();'

Comment: I don't know, I will try, If i found any solution i will tell you again, congrats.